# Bit arrays usage and filtering in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, bitarray

I have a bit array. And I want to filter based on if certain bits are ON or OFF.
Looking at the Elasticsearch 2.3 docs, I don't see anything about bitarrays.

But it seems I can use an Array of Booleans or a Binary field.

Example:
Let's say I have 2 documents each with a bit array field. Doc1 has 011100 and Doc2 has 00001 in that field. And I want to filter by 011000 which in this case only gives Doc1.

Any ideas how to do this in Elasticsearch?

Thanks you.

Edit: Another idea:

If I turn the bit array into many Bool fields, then it works. The doc might look ugly but it works.
Basically if the bit array is 32 bit, then I will have 32 bool fields. Is that the best way to implement this?

Comment: which solution did you implement? 32 bool fields or bit position ?

Comment: I did the bit position. Also I opened a feature request on Elasticsearch to ask for Bitarrays. Please vote it up if interested: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you could change it to an array containing the bit-index which are set. That is `011100` would be`[ 1 , 2 ,3 ]` and then use a `terms` query to do an `or` or a `must` query for `and`

Example :

```
a)  document with "111" 

put test/test/1
{
   "bit_position" : [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}

b) document with 010
put test/test/2
{
   "bit_position": [
      2
   ]
}

c) or-ing with 101

post test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
           "bit_position": [
              1,
              3
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Do you know by any chance how it can sort based on `bit_position` instead of filter? So for example sort based on `bit_position=3`

Comment: if you want to sort by `bit_postion` you could use [sort with mode max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_option) . is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: What I want to do is to return results with bit_position=3 first. Then the rest. And I want to avoid the script feature since it is not very optimized from my understanding. What I'm thinking about doing now is to make 2 different requests to ES, one with bit_position=3 and one with bit_position!=3 and then add the results together. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: in that case you could probably just use [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-weight) give a additonal boost to documents with bit_postion=3 .This would ensure all documents with bit_position=3 would show up higher.  .