# Elasticsearch : feature vector similarity / overlap scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

**Scenario**

I have around 25 million products, for each product I have generated 2048 bit features (2048 true/false boolean values). I have generated a bit array for each product.

Example vector: [0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 1]

**Problem**

I am trying to find matches across the documents based the number of common features overlapping. Given a product 'A', I want to find the most similar products just based on the number of features. No important features, no term frequency or idf is necessary. The problem is none of the approaches I am able to find a match in less than 1 sec.

**My Approach 1**

Create 2048 fields and store for each product. When finding similarity for a particular product, just query on fields whose bool value is true.

*Document Structure*

```
{
    "doc_id": "001",
    "feature_0001": true,
    "feature_0002": false,
    "feature_0003": true,
    .
    .
    .
    "feature_2048": false
}
```

*Query*

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "feature_0001": true
                    }
                },
                .
                .
                .
                {
                    "match": {
                        "feature_0003": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**My Approach 2**

Based on this SO answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/39112733/1179958 )
Create an array for integers whose bit positions are ON.

*Document Structure*

```
{
    "doc_id": "001",
    "positions": [0, 2, ... , 2045]
}
```

*Query*

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "positions": [2, 3, 6, ... , 2046]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**My Approach 3**

Same as approach 2 except using multiple term queries for each integer instead of single terms query [turns out it had minor performance improvement which I didn't expect]

**My Approach 4**

Custom similarity module based on [this link](http://stefansavev.com/blog/custom-similarity-for-elasticsearch/)

Converted the bit positions to space separated strings and used whitespace analyzer.

**Hardware specs**

Linode 12 GB configuration with SSD disk and 6 GB heap configuration.

**Questions**

1. How can I improve the speed of search to under 1 second?
2. Should I use different mapping?
3. Is there an option to do BIT AND operation if I choose to index 2048 features as bit array ?